# How to update and insert multiple row data at the same time with button click (axios + laravel + vuejs)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

everyone, I want to make sales quotation form with editing feature, so if a user make a mistake when input the data, they can edit, update and add more item. And yeah, im still learning and newbie in this.

Last information I got from google is using axios.all, but i dont know how to use it, already search for a week and still got stuck with this problem.

The main problem is in Detail.vue and SalesQuotationsController.php.

I tried to give you all as much information, hope it can help you to identified it.

Thank You.

**API**

1. api.php

   ```
   <?php

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

   Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

   Route::resource('/salesquotation', 'API\SalesQuotationsController')->except(['create', 'show', 'update']);
   Route::post('/salesquotation/insertProduct', 'API\SalesQuotationsController@insertProduct');
   Route::post('/salesquotation/{id}', 'API\SalesQuotationsController@update');
   });
   ```

**Javascript**

2. store.js

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue'

   import Vuex from 'vuex'

   import authVuex from './stores/auth.js'        
   import sqVuex from './stores/salesquotation.js'


   Vue.use(Vuex)


   const store = new Vuex.Store({
   modules: {
       authVuex,         
       sqVuex

   },
     state: {
       token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
       errors: []
   },
   getters: {

       isAuth: state => {
           return state.token != "null" && state.token != null
       }
   },
   mutations: {

       SET_TOKEN(state, payload) {
           state.token = payload
       },
       SET_ERRORS(state, payload) {
           state.errors = payload
       },
       CLEAR_ERRORS(state) {
           state.errors = []
       }
   }
   })

   export default store
   ```
3. router.js

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import Router from 'vue-router'
   import store from './store.js'

   import IndexSalesQuotation from './pages/transactions/salesquotation/Index.vue'
   import ListSalesQuotation from './pages/transactions/salesquotation/List.vue'
   import AddSalesQuotation from './pages/transactions/salesquotation/Add.vue'
   import EditSalesQuotation from './pages/transactions/salesquotation/Edit.vue'


   Vue.use(Router)

   const router = new Router({
       mode: 'history',
       routes: [
           {
               path: '/salesquotation',
               component: IndexSalesQuotation,
               meta: { requiresAuth: true },
               children: [
                   {
                       path: 'list',
                       name: 'salesQuotRoute.showList',
                       component: ListSalesQuotation,
                       meta: { title: 'Sales Quotation' }
                   },
                   {
                       path: 'add',
                       name: 'salesQuotRoute.add',
                       component: AddSalesQuotation,
                       meta: { title: 'Create New Sales Quotation' }
                   },
                   {
                       path: 'edit/:id',
                       name: 'salesQuotRoute.edit',
                       component: EditSalesQuotation,
                       meta: { title: 'Edit Sales Quotation' }
                   },                      
               ]
           },
       ]
   });

   export default router
   ```
4. app.js

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import router from './router.js'
   import store from './store.js'
   import App from './App.vue'

   import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
   import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2'

   Vue.use(VueSweetalert2)
   Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

   import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'
   import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

   import { mapActions, mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex'

   Vue.component('my-cur-input', {
       props: ["value"],
       template: `
           <div>
               <input type="text" v-model="displayValue" @blur="isInputActive = false"  @focus="isInputActive = true" style="width:100px"/>
           </div>`,
       data: function() {
           return {
               // value = 0,
               isInputActive: false
           }
       },
       computed: {
           displayValue: {
               get: function() {
                   if (this.isInputActive) {
                       return this.value.toString()
                   } else {
                       var stro = this.value;
                       stro = parseFloat(stro).toFixed(2).split('.');
                       if (stro[0].length >= 4) {
                           stro[0] = stro[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1.');
                       }                           
                       return "Rp " + stro.join(',');
                   }
               },
               set: function(modifiedValue) {

                   let newValue = parseFloat(modifiedValue.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ""))
                   let value = this.value

                   if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                       newValue = 0
                   }
                   this.$emit('input', newValue)
                   this.$emit('blur', newValue)
               }
           }
       }
   });

   new Vue({
       el: '#raz',
       router,
       store,
       components: {
           App
       },
       computed: {
           ...mapGetters(['isAuth']),
           ...mapState(['token']),
           ...mapState('userVuex', {
               user_authenticated: state => state.authenticated
           })
       },

       methods: {
           ...mapActions('userVuex', ['getUserLogin']),

       watch: {
           token() {
           },
           user_authenticated() {
           }
       },
       created() {
           if (this.isAuth) {
               this.getUserLogin()
           }
       }
   })
   ```
5. api.js

   ```
   import axios from 'axios';
   import store from './store.js'

   const $axios = axios.create({
       baseURL: '/api',
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }
   });

   $axios.interceptors.request.use (
       function (config) {
           const token = store.state.token
           if (token) config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
           return config;
       },
       function (error) {
           return Promise.reject (error);
       }
   );        
   export default $axios;
   ```
6. salesquotation.js

   ```
   import $axios from '../api.js'

   const state = () => ({
       custitems: [], 
       items: [], 
       units: [],
       custs: [],
       list_sq: [],
       detail_sq: [],
       page: 1,
       idForEdit: ''           
   })

   const mutations = {

       ASSIGN_CUSTEM(state, payload) {
           state.custitems = payload
       },
       ASSIGN_ITEM(state, payload) {
           state.items = payload
       },
       ASSIGN_UNITS(state, payload) {
           state.units = payload
       },
       ASSIGN_CUST(state, payload) {
           state.custs = payload
       },
       ASSIGN_DETAIL(state, payload) {
           state.detail_sq = payload
       },
       ASSIGN_LIST(state, payload) {
           state.list_sq = payload
       },
       SET_PAGE(state, payload) {
           state.page = payload
       },
       SET_ID_UPDATE(state, payload) {
           state.idForEdit = payload
       }
   }

   const actions = {

       getUnit({ commit }) {
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               $axios.get(`/unit`)
               .then((response) => {
                   commit('ASSIGN_UNITS', response.data.data)
                   resolve(response.data)
               })
           })
       },

       getProd({ commit, state }, payload) {
           let search = payload.search
           payload.loading(true)
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               $axios.get(`/custem?page=${state.page}&q=${search}`)
               .then((response) => {
                   commit('ASSIGN_CUSTEM', response.data)
                   payload.loading(false)
                   resolve(response.data)
               })
           })
       },
       getCust({ commit, state }, payload) {
           let search = payload.search
           payload.loading(true)
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               $axios.get(`/cust?page=${state.page}&q=${search}`)
               .then((response) => {
                   commit('ASSIGN_CUST', response.data)
                   payload.loading(false)
                   resolve(response.data)
               })
           })
       },
       createSalesQuot({commit}, payload) {
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               $axios.post(`/salesquotation`, payload)
               .then((response) => {
                   resolve(response.data)
               })
           })
       },
       insertProduct({commit}, payload) {
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               $axios.post(`/salesquotation/insertProduct`, payload)
               .then((response) => {
                   resolve(response.data)
               })
           })
       },
       getListSalesQuot({ commit, state }, payload) {
           let search = typeof payload.search != 'undefined' ? payload.search:''
           let status = typeof payload.status != 'undefined' ? payload.status:''
               return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                   $axios.get(`/salesquotation?page=${state.page}&q=${search}&status=${status}`)
                   .then((response) => {
                       commit('ASSIGN_LIST', response.data)
                       resolve(response.data)
               })
           })
       },
       getDetailSalesQuot({ commit }, payload) {
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               $axios.get(`/salesquotation/${payload}/edit`)
               .then((response) => {
                   commit('ASSIGN_DETAIL', response.data.data)
                   resolve(response.data)
               })
           })
       },
       editSalesQuot({ commit }, payload) {
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               $axios.get(`/salesquotation/${payload}/edit`)
               .then((response) => {
                   resolve(response.data)
               })
           })
       },
       updateSalesQuot({ commit }, payload) {
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               $axios.put(`/salesquotation/${payload.id}`, payload)
               .then((response) => {
                   resolve(response.data)
               })
               .catch((error) => {
                   if (error.response.status == 422) {
                       commit('SET_ERRORS', error.response.data.errors, { root: true })
                   }
               })
           })
       },
   }

   export default {
       namespaced: true,
       state,
       actions,
       mutations
   }
   ```

**Vue**

1. List.vue

   ```
   <template>
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="panel">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                   <router-link :to="{ name: 'salesQuotRoute.add' }" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-flat">Create Sales Quotation</router-link>
                   <div class="pull-right">
                       <div class="row">                      

                           <div class="col-md-6">
                               <select v-model="filter_status" class="form-control">
                                   <option value="3">All</option>
                                   <option value="cancel">Canceled</option>
                                   <option value="done">Done</option>
                                   <option value="open">Open</option>
                               </select>
                           </div>

                           <div class="col-md-6">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." v-model="search">
                           </div>

                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>

               <hr>

               <div class="panel-body">
                   <b-table striped hover bordered responsive :items="listSQForm.data" :fields="fields" show-empty>
                       <template v-slot:cell(master_cust_id)="row">
                           <p>Name: <strong>{{ row.item.customer ? row.item.customer.cust_name:'' }}</strong></p>
                           <p>Telp: {{ row.item.customer.phone }}</p>
                           <p>Add: {{ row.item.customer.address1 }}</p>
                       </template>
                       <template v-slot:cell(amount)="row">
                           <p>{{ row.item.amount | currency }}</p>
                       </template>
                       <template v-slot:cell(status)="row">
                           <p v-html="row.item.status_label"></p>
                       </template>
                       <template v-slot:cell(actions)="row">
                           <router-link :to="{ name: 'salesQuotRoute.edit', params: {id: row.item.id} }" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></router-link>
                       </template>
                   </b-table>

                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <p v-if="listSQForm.data"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> {{ listSQForm.data.length }} item dari {{ listSQForm.meta.total }} total data</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <div class="pull-right">
                               <b-pagination
                                   v-model="page"
                                   :total-rows="listSQForm.meta.total"
                                   :per-page="listSQForm.meta.per_page"
                                   aria-controls="listSQForm"
                                   v-if="listSQForm.data && listSQForm.data.length > 0"
                                   ></b-pagination>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </template>

   <script>
   import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'

   export default {
       name: 'DataSalesQuotation',
       created() {
           this.getListSalesQuot({
               status: this.filter_status,
               search: this.search
           }) 
       },
       data() {
           return {
               fields: [
                   { key: 'sq_number', label: 'Quotation'},
                   { key: 'master_cust_id', label: 'Customer' },
                   { key: 'amount', label: 'Amount' },
                   { key: 'description', label: 'Description' },
                   { key: 'proforma_invoice_number', label: 'Proforma Invoice' },
                   { key: 'status', label: 'Status' },
                   { key: 'sales_order_number', label: 'SO Number' },
                   { key: 'actions', label: 'Action' }

               ],
               search: '',
               filter_status: 3
           }
       },
       computed: {
           ...mapState('sqVuex', {
               listSQForm: state => state.list_sq
           }),
           page: {
               get() {
                   return this.$store.state.sqVuex.page
               },
               set(val) {
                   this.$store.commit('sqVuex/SET_PAGE', val)
               }
           }
       },
       filters: {
           currency: function(money) {
           return accounting.formatMoney(money, "Rp ", 2, ".", ",")
           }
       },
       watch: {
           page() {
               this.getListSalesQuot({
                   status: this.filter_status,
                   search: this.search
               })
           },
           search() {
               this.getListSalesQuot({
                   status: this.filter_status,
                   search: this.search
               })
           },
           filter_status() {
               this.getListSalesQuot({
                   status: this.filter_status,
                   search: this.search
               })
           }
       },
       methods: {
           ...mapActions('sqVuex', ['getListSalesQuot']) 
       }
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Edit.vue

   ```
   <template>
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="panel">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Add Sales Quotation</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">

                   <salesQuot-form ref="salesQuotForm"></salesQuot-form>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-flat" @click.prevent="submit">
                           <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save
                       </button>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </template>
   <script>
       import { mapActions, mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'
       import FormSalesQuot from './Form.vue'
       export default {
           name: 'AddSalesQuotation',
           methods: {
               submit() {
                   this.$refs.salesQuotForm.submit()
               }
           },
           components: {
               'salesQuot-form': FormSalesQuot
           }
       }
   </script>
   ```
3. Detail.vue

   ```
   <template>
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="panel">
               <div class="panel-body">
                   <div class="row">

                       <div class="col-md-6 table table-responsive-xl" >

                           <h4> <strong>Customer</strong> </h4>
                           <hr>

                           <v-select :options="customerData.data"
                               v-model="sq.customer"
                               @search="onSearch" 
                               label="cust_name"
                               placeholder="Search..." 
                               :filterable="false">
                               <template slot="no-options">
                                   Search Customer
                               </template>
                               <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
                                   {{ option.cust_number }}:   {{ option.cust_name }}
                               </template>
                           </v-select>
                       </div>


                       <div class="col-md-6 table table-responsive-xl" v-if="sq.customer">

                           <h4> <strong>Customer Info</strong> </h4>
                           <hr>
                           <table class="table table-hover table-responsive-xl">
                               <tr>
                                   <th width="15%">Customer Number </th>
                                   <td width="2%">:</td>
                                   <td>{{ sq.customer.cust_number }}</td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                   <th>Name </th>
                                   <td>:</td>
                                   <td>{{ sq.customer.cust_name }}</td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                   <th>Main Address </th>
                                   <td>:</td>
                                   <td>{{ sq.customer.address1 }}</td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                   <th>Alt. Address </th>
                                   <td>:</td>
                                   <td>{{ sq.customer.address2 }}</td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                   <th>Phone </th>
                                   <td>:</td>
                                   <td>{{ sq.customer.phone }}</td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                   <th>Contact Person </th>
                                   <td>:</td>
                                   <td>{{ sq.customer.contact }}</td>
                               </tr>
                           </table>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-md-6 form-group" :class="{ 'has-error': errors.desc }">
                           <textarea cols="3" rows="3" class="form-control" v-model="sq.desc"></textarea>
                           <p class="text-danger" v-if="errors.desc">{{ errors.desc[0] }}</p>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 20px">

                           <h4><strong>Detail Transaction</strong> </h4>
                           <hr>

                           <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="margin-bottom: 10px" @click="addProduct">Tambah</button>
                           <div class="text-uppercase text-bold">id selected: {{ selected  }}</div>

                           <div class="table table-responsive-xl">
                                   <b-table-simple striped hover bordered responsive show-empty style="height:500px">
                                   <b-thead>
                                       <b-tr>
                                           <b-th>
                                               <label class="form-checkbox">
                                                   <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll" @click="select">
                                                   <i class="form-icon"></i>
                                               </label>
                                           </b-th>

                                           <b-th>ID</b-th>
                                           <b-th width="35%" id="min-width">Product</b-th>
                                           <b-th width="5%" id="min-width">Quantity</b-th>
                                           <b-th id="min-width">Price</b-th>
                                           <b-th id="min-width">Subtotal</b-th>
                                           <b-th id="min-width">Actions</b-th>
                                       </b-tr>
                                   </b-thead>
                                   <b-tbody>
                                       <b-tr v-for="(row, index) in sq.detailSQ" :key="index">                                             

                                           <b-td>
                                               <label class="form-checkbox">
                                                   <input type="checkbox" :value="row.id" v-model="selected" @change="unCheckAll">
                                                   <i class="form-icon"></i>
                                               </label>                                                    
                                           </b-td>

                                           <b-td>{{row.id}}</b-td>

                                           <b-td>
                                                   <v-select :options="productData.data"
                                                       v-model="row.product"
                                                       @search="onSearchProduct" 
                                                       label="item_name_alt"
                                                       placeholder="Search..." 
                                                       :filterable="false"
                                                       style="width:300px">
                                                       <template slot="no-options">
                                                           Search Product
                                                       </template>

                                                       <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
                                                           {{ option.peloduk.item_number }}: {{ option.item_name_alt }}
                                                       </template>

                                                   </v-select>
                                           </b-td>

                                           <b-td>
                                               <div class="input-group">
                                                   <input type="number" v-model="row.quantity" class="form-control" @blur="calculate(index)" style="width:70px">
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon">{{ row.product != null && row.product.satuanunit.unit == row.product.satuanunit.unit ? row.product.satuanunit.unit:'Unit' }}</span>
                                               </div>                                                  
                                           </b-td>

                                           <b-td> 
                                               <div class='input-group'> 
                                                   <my-cur-input v-model="row.price" @blur="calculate(index)"></my-cur-input>
                                               </div>
                                           </b-td>

                                           <b-td> {{ row.subtotal | currency }}</b-td>

                                           <b-td>
                                                   <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"  @click="isDone(row.id)">
                                                       <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
                                                   </button>
                                           </b-td>
                                       </b-tr>
                                   </b-tbody>

                                   <b-tfoot>
                                       <b-tr>
                                       <b-th id="total" colspan="5" class="text-right">Total :</b-th>
                                       <b-td>{{ total | currency }}</b-td>
                                       <b-td> <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"  @click="isDoneAll(selected)">
                                               </button>
                                       </b-td>
                                       </b-tr>
                                   </b-tfoot>
                                   </b-table-simple>    
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </template>

   <script>
       import { mapActions, mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'
       import vSelect from 'vue-select'
       import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css'
       import {Money} from 'v-money'
       import _ from 'lodash'
       import axios from 'axios';

       export default {

           name: 'DetailSalesQuotation',
           created() {
               this.getDetailSalesQuot(this.$route.params.id).then((res) => {
                   this.sq = {
                       customer: res.data.customer,    
                       desc: res.data.description,
                       detailSQ: res.data.detail
                   }
               })
           },
           data() {
               return {
                   selectAll: false,
                   selected: [],
                   amount: 0, 
                   customer_change: false,
                   sq: {
                       customer_id: '',
                       detailSQ: [
                           { product: null, quantity: 1, price: 0, subtotal: 0 }
                       ]
                   },

               }
           },              

           watch: {
           },
           filters: {
               currency: function(money) {
               return accounting.formatMoney(money, "Rp ", 2, ".", ",")
               }
           },
           computed: {
               ...mapState(['errors']),
               ...mapState('sqVuex', {

                   detailSQForm: state => state.detail_sq,
                   customerData: state => state.custs,
                   productData: state => state.custitems,

               }),                 

               total() {
                   return _.sumBy(this.sq.detailSQ, function(o) {
                       return parseFloat(o.subtotal)
                   })
               }
           },
           methods: {
               ...mapMutations('sqVuex', ['SET_ID_UPDATE']),
               ...mapActions('sqVuex', ['getDetailSalesQuot','getCust', 'getProd', 'updateSalesQuot', 'insertProduct']),
               onSearch(search, loading) {

                   this.getCust({
                       search: search,
                       loading: loading
                   })
               },

               onSearchProduct(search, loading) {

                   this.getProd({
                       search: search,
                       loading: loading
                   })
               },
               addProduct() {
                       this.sq.detailSQ.push({ product: null, quantity: null, price: 0, subtotal: 0 })                     
               },   

               calculate(index) {
                   let data = this.sq.detailSQ[index]
                   if (data.product != null) {
                       data.price = data.price
                       data.subtotal = (parseFloat(data.price) * (parseFloat(data.quantity))).toFixed(2)
                   }
               },
               select() {
                   this.selected = [];

                   if (!this.selectAll) {
                       for (let i in this.sq.detailSQ) {
                           this.selected.push(this.sq.detailSQ[i].id);
                       }
                   }
               },
               unCheckAll(){
                   if(this.selected.length == this.sq.detailSQ.length){
                       this.selectAll = true;
                   }
                   else{
                       this.selectAll = false;
                   }
               },


               //this is the problem
               submit() {
               this.isSuccess = false
                   let filter = _.filter(this.sq.detailSQ, function(item) {
                       return item.product != null
                   })
                    if (filter.length > 0) {
                        Object.assign(this.sq, { id: this.$route.params.id })
                           axios.all([                            
                               this.updateSalesQuot(this.sq)
                           ])
                    }                     
               },
               //this is the problem

           },
           components: 
               {
               vSelect,
               Money
               }
       }

   </script>
   ```

**Backend Laravel**

Due to characters limitation, model and collection not included here

1. SalesQuotationsController

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\SalesQuotation;
   use App\SalesQuotationDetail;
   use DB;

   use App\Http\Resources\SalesQuotationCollection;

   class SalesQuotationsController extends Controller
   {
       public function index() 
       {
           $search = request()->q; 
           $user = request()->user();      

           $salesquot = SalesQuotation::with(['user', 'detail', 'customer'])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
               ->whereHas('customer', function($q) use($search) {
                   $q->where('cust_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
               });

           if (in_array(request()->status, [0,1])) {
               $salesquot = $salesquot->where('status', request()->status);
           }           

           $salesquot = $salesquot->paginate(10);
           return new SalesQuotationCollection($salesquot);
       }

       public function store(Request $request)
       {                       
                   DB::beginTransaction();
                   try{                

                       $sqend = SalesQuotation::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
                       if ( ! $sqend )
                           $sqnum = 0;
                       else 
                           $sqnum = substr($sqend->sq_number, 2);
                           $urutansqnum = 'SQ' . sprintf('%04d', intval($sqnum) + 1);

                       $piend = SalesQuotation::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
                       if (! $piend)
                           $pinum = 0;
                       else
                           $pinum = substr($piend->proforma_invoice_number, 2);
                           $urutanpinum = 'PI' . sprintf('%04d', intval($pinum) + 1);              

                       $user = $request->user();

                       $salesquot = SalesQuotation::create([
                           'sq_number' => $urutansqnum,
                           'master_cust_id' => $request->customer_id['id'],
                           'user_id' => $user->id,
                           'amount' => 0,
                           'description' => $request->desc,
                           'proforma_invoice_number' => $urutanpinum,
                           'status' => 'open'
                       ]);

                       $amount = 0; 
                       foreach ($request->detailSQ as $row) {

                           if (!is_null($row['product'])) {                

                                   $subtotal = $row['price'] * $row['quantity'];

                                try{

                                   SalesQuotationDetail::create([
                                       'sales_quotation_id' => $salesquot->id,
                                       'master_cust_id' => $request->customer_id['id'],
                                       'master_cust_item_id' => $row['product']['id'],
                                       'master_unit_id' => $row['product']['master_unit_id'],
                                       'quantity' => $row['quantity'],
                                       'price' => $row['price'],
                                       'subtotal' => $subtotal,
                                       'description' => $request->desc
                                   ]);

                                   $amount += $subtotal; 
                               }
                           }

                       $salesquot->update(['amount' => $amount]);

                       DB::commit();
                       return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $salesquot]);
                   }
                   catch (\Exception $e){
                       DB::rollback(); 
                       return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'data' => $e->getMessage()]);
                   }

       }

       public function update(Request $request, $id)
       {               
           DB::beginTransaction();
           try{

               $user = $request->user();

               $slsqt = SalesQuotation::find($id);

               $slsqt->update([
                   'master_cust_id' => $request->customer['id'],
                   'description' => $request->desc
               ]);

               $amount = 0;

               foreach ($request->detailSQ as $row) {

                   if (!is_null($row['product'])) {
                           $subtotal = $row['price'] * $row['quantity'];
                        try{

                           $sld = SalesQuotationDetail::find($row['id']);                          
                                   $sld->update([

                                       'master_cust_id' => $request->customer['id'],
                                       'master_cust_item_id' => $row['product']['id'],
                                       'master_unit_id' => $row['product']['master_unit_id'],
                                       'quantity' => $row['quantity'],
                                       'price' => $row['price'],
                                       'subtotal' => $subtotal,
                                       'description' => $request->desc
                                   ]);

                                   $amount += $subtotal; 
                       }
                   }

               $slsqt->update(['amount' => $amount]);       

               DB::commit();
               return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $slsqt]);
           }
           catch (\Exception $e){
               DB::rollback();
               return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'data' => $e->getMessage(), $sld]);
               // return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'data' => $slsqt]);
           }

       }

       public function insertProduct(request $request)
       {
           DB::beginTransaction();
                   try{

                       $amount = 0; 
                       foreach ($request->detailSQ as $row) {

                           if (!is_null($row['product'])) {
                                   $subtotal = $row['price'] * $row['quantity'];               
                                try{

                                   $sqd = SalesQuotationDetail::create([
                                       'sales_quotation_id' => $request->id,
                                       'master_cust_id' => $request->customer_id['id'],
                                       'master_cust_item_id' => $row['product']['id'],
                                       'master_unit_id' => $row['product']['master_unit_id'],
                                       'quantity' => $row['quantity'],
                                       'price' => $row['price'],
                                       'subtotal' => $subtotal,
                                       'description' => $request->desc
                                   ]);

                                   $amount += $subtotal; 
                               }
                           }

                       $salesquot->update(['amount' => $amount]);

                       DB::commit();
                       return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $sqd]);
                   }
                   catch (\Exception $e){
                       DB::rollback(); 
                       return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'data' => $e->getMessage()]);
                   }
       }

       public function edit($id)
       {
           $sq = SalesQuotation::with(['customer', 'detail', 'detail.product', 'detail.product.satuanunit', 'detail.satuanunit'])->find($id);
           return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $sq]);
       }
   }
   ```

**Database Screenshot**

1. SalesQuotations

[SalesQuotations Data Structure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaKqj.png)

[SalesQuotations Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGKsk.png)

2. SalesQuotationsDetail

[SalesQuotationsDetail Data Structure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH866.png)

[SalesQuotationsDetail Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqyBl.png)

**Program Screenshot**

1. List Form
   [List Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCB75.png)
2. Transaction Form
   [Transaction Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz3QD.png)
3. Transaction Form Continued
   [Transaction Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe9v2.png)

Comment: Hi, there's a lot of info there but you don't really describe what the current and desired behaviours are. Have you considered creating a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Well, the conclusion is, when I posted transaction and then I make mistake, lets look program screenshot number 3, thats transaction that I want to update, 1st and 2nd lines are the items I saved before, thats why you can see the ID in the first column and then 3rd and 4th lines are the items I want to add, because I forgot to add when the first time I created this transaction, thats why you see no ID in the first column, after I input all the data, I want to save all the changes I have been made, this where I dont know how to do it. I hope you understand my problem. Thank You.